# How to customize the colors of Qt applications in Ubuntu (16.10)?

Tags: themes, qt

After quite a lot of searching, I see nowhere how to change the colors of my Qt applications.

I already created a custom dark gtk theme in `~/.themes/` by modifying the default Ambiance, but now I need to also change Qt apps. And funnily, they already display in dark (sometimes too dark) so I may have changed it a long time ago (no idea how).

For example I use **Scribus** and **Mendeleydesktop** that use Qt (Qt5 and Qt4 respectively).

I tried:

1. to create a css style sheet with `background: blue; color: green;` as a test, but executing:

   ```
   mendeleydesktop -stylesheet myqtstyle.css
   ```

   does not affect anything (just complains: `Could not parse application stylesheet`)
2. `qt4-config`, no effect.
3. I searched in `gconf-editor` and `dconf-editor` if there are settings for Qt, no luck.
4. I modified the gtk-3.20, gtk-3.0 and gtk-2 files of my theme, no effect.

Does someone have a simple solution for customizing my Qt apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to set a style sheet when launching a Qt application (as you have detailed in the question):

```
{application_name} -stylesheet {path_to_style_sheet}
```

This should work, however it is possible that the developer of the application is forcing a particular style within the application code so it will not always work.

The reason you are receiving the error message `Could not parse application stylesheet` is because the test style sheet you have produced is not a valid Qt style sheet.

The Qt documentation provides information on creating your own style sheets and links to these are below:

- Qt4 - [Qt4 Style Sheet Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html#stylesheet).
- Qt5 - [Qt5 Style Sheet Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html).

Given that you have received an error message relating to parsing, I would assume that it will work if you provide the path to a valid style sheet as a command line argument.

You may find it difficult creating a style sheet if you are not familiar with the standard Qt widget class names. Further information on these can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try that! Is there a way to create a single global stylesheet for all my Qt applications? Isn't there already a default one somewhere in the system?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to force a style sheet to be used globally. You can obviously use the command line option above for each application using the same path. I believe you can force a style (a software library) globally but I have no experience of using it. I believe for Qt4 this is the package qt4-qtconfig and for Qt5 it is qt5ct so it may be worth a search using those names.